# Angular 2 - NgForm null when submit a form

Tags: angular

Hi everyone i am doing a "dinamic" form with Angular and i am having some problems to get the values that input in form, my code is:

HTML

```
<form  #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm)" *ngFor="let con of controls" novalidate>
  <div class="form-group" *ngIf = "con.type != 'submit'">
    <label for="{{con.id}}">{{con.label}}</label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="con.name" type="{{con.type}}" class="{{con.class}}" name="{{con.id}}">
 </div>
 <input  *ngIf = "con.type == 'submit'"  type="submit" class="{{con.class}}" value={{con.label}}> 
</form>
```

Component:

```
import { Component ,Input} from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'form-tag',
  templateUrl: './form.html',
})

export class FormComponent {
    @Input() controls: any[];

    onSubmit(sub: NgForm)
    {
        console.log(sub.email);
    }
}
```

the problem is that when i submit the form console.log(sub.email); return an empty object

Answer (score 1):

Since you use ngForm, it's a template driven form and not a reactive one. In template driven forms you need to pass myForm.value to onSubmit():

```
onSubmit(myForm.value)
```

Also, from your code sample, it's not clear what's con.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really really sure what you're trying to do but it seems like you're looping over controls with the `<form>` tag instead of just with the `div.form-group` and the `<input />` itself.

Maybe wrap those in an `<ng-template />` and loop through it and not the `<form>` tag?

So something like this:

```html
<form  #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm)" novalidate>
    <ng-template *ngFor="let con of controls">
      <div class="form-group" *ngIf="con.type != 'submit'">
        <label for="{{con.id}}">{{con.label}}</label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="con.name" type="{{con.type}}" class="{{con.class}}" name="{{con.id}}" />
     </div>
     <input *ngIf="con.type == 'submit'" type="submit" class="{{con.class}}" [value]="con.label" />
</form>
```